# Robot Framework selenium Unable to Open Browser for Edge Browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, path, robotframework, microsoft-edge

I am trying to Open browser for **Edge** using Robot Framework selenium keyword but log message i got as **"WebDriverException: Message: 'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH"**

Below Libraries are installed
robotframework                     4.0.2
robotframework-seleniumlibrary     5.1.3
selenium                           3.141.0

From the code under the path C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py i can see **MicrosoftWebDriver.exe** but the webdriver i downloaded as **msedgedriver.exe**.
How to solve this?

```
def __init__(self, executable_path=**'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe',**
             capabilities=None, port=0, verbose=False, service_log_path=None,
             log_path=None, keep_alive=False):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should provide a full path to the `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe` file here.
Like

```
 executable_path=**'C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe',
```

or add that folder to you machine PATH settings